# Are questions about the car's interior right for this site?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm having a hard time understanding why one of my questions is closed

Question can be found at

[Remove smell / odor from car's interior](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/remove-smell-from-cars-interior)

As I mentioned in my comments, Vehicle Maintenance and Repair is more than just working on the motor and fixing up the body and therefore I feel this question is perfectly acceptable.

Please advise so I may improve.

Answer (score 8):

I feel the question is on-topic, and should be allowed, but I am not willing to simply reverse another mods decision without some input from him and or the community.

The faq states

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair -
>   Stack Exchange is for mechanics and
>   DIY-enthusiast owners of cars, trucks,
>   and motorcycles.

which could stand to be more specific, but based on the current faq would be a valid question.

The faq also states

> What kind of questions should I not
>   ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical,
>   answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty,
>   open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other
>   questions off the front page.

The question also passes these requirements as well

Read more [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is somewhat borderline, but probably acceptable because:

1. The golden rule: **is this question so off-topic that a professional mechanic would be *offended* that it is here?** I don't think that's true here. It's definitely borderline, but "odor makes car undrivable" is at least a real, concrete motor vehicle problem with actual solutions.
2. On smaller sites, we want to encourage growth and give borderline questions the benefit of the doubt.

Therefore I'm going to go ahead and re-open it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Just my $.02, but this is more a detailing question. I never deal with cleaning vehicles, or removing smells from the interior. The only time I had to clean anything was when a lady spilled her milk in the trunk, and it ruined a module. Also, since the milk sat in her spare tire bay and basically rotted from the sun, there was a ton of maggots in there. I can understand why he closed it, but would not feel insulted in answering it. 
If you want to stick to a truly "Maintenance and Repair" site, then this question would be invalid IMHO. Detailing does not equal troubleshooting, maint, or repair. Interior repair and replacement should be allowed, but cleaning and detailing is not what technicians do for a living.